# Where I should I prepare my data? In awakeFromNib, viewDidLoad or something else

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I am still relatively new to iOS programming. Here is a question that confused me for a long time.

So in one of the view controllers, before this view controller is pushed into the navigation item, I am passing one parameter, say userId, to it in the `prepareForSegue` from previous view controller. And when this view controller is loading (initialising) based on the `userId` from the previous view controller, I am making a network call to fetch a list of information that's related to this user and then populating this information to the model of the current view controller.

Where should I put the logic of this data preparation?

Comment: I mean all you guys provided me a good solution to the question.
Thank you very much for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `viewDidLoad:` should be fine for common storyboard use because the storyboard does not reuse view controller. Anyway, for the completeness of my view controller usage scenario, I tend to use this pattern:

- Start loading remote data asynchronously in `viewWillAppear:`
- Stop loading remote data in `viewWillDisappear:`

This make sure that your data will be always updated to the current `userId` because the ID might be changed after `viewDidLoad`, e.g. in case of view controller reuse or accessing `.view` property before setting `userId`.

You should also track if your data has been loaded. For example, you could make a private boolean field named `_isDataLoaded`, set it to `true` when finish loading data and set it to `false` when cancelling loading data or setting new `userId`.

To sum it up, the pattern in my idea should be something like this:

```
@interface UserViewControler : UIViewController {
    bool _isDataLoaded;
    NSURLConnection _dataConnection;
}

@implementation UserViewController

-(void) setUserId:(int)userId {
    if (_userId != userId) {
        _userId = userId;
        _isDataLoaded = false;
    }
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!_isDataLoaded) {
        _dataConnection = // init data connection here
        _dataConnection.delegate = self;
        [_dataConnection start];
    }
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (_dataConnection) {
        [_dataConnection cancel];
        _dataConnection = nil;
        _isDataLoaded = false;
    }
}

// NSURLConnection call this when finish
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    _isDataLoaded = true;
    _dataConnection = nil;
}

// NSURLConnection call this when fail to load data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    _isDataLoaded = false;
    _dataConnection = nil;
}
```

It depends on what framework you use to retrieve data from remote server, but the pattern should be like this. This will ensure that:

- You will load data only when the view appear.
- View controller will not loading more data after disappear.
- In case of same `userId`, data would not be downloaded again.
- Support view controller reuse.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    // initialize stuff
}
```

Although, it may be better to do the network call and gather all this information into a custom class that contains all the information, and then perform the segue.  Then all you have to do in the new view controller is pulled data out of the object (which would still be done in `viewDidLoad`).

Arguably, this method might be better because if there's a problem with the network, you can display an error message and then not perform the segue, giving the user an easier way to reattempt the same action, or at least they'll be on the page to reattempt the same action after leaving app to check network settings and coming back.

Of course, you could just segue forward always, and segue backward if there's a network error, but I think this looks sloppier.

Also, it's worth noting that if you're presenting the information with a `UICollectionView` or a `UITableView`, the presenting logic can (should) be moved out of `viewDidLoad` and into the collection/table data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is make custom initializers.

```
+(instancetype)initWithUserID:(NSString)userID;
```

Here is an example of the implementation.

```
+(instancetype)initWithUserID:(NSString *)userID {
    return [[self alloc] initWithUserID:userID];
}

-(id)initWithUserID:(NSString *)userID {
    self = [self initWithNibName:@"TheNameOfTheNib" bundle:nil];
    if(self) {
        _userID = userID;
    }
    //do something with _userID here. 
    //example: start loading content from API
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
//or do something with userID here instead.
}
```

The other thing I would suggest is make a custom class that loads data and uses blocks.

Then you can do something like this

```
[API loadDataForUserID:userID withCompletionBlock^(NSArray *blockArray) {
     //in this case I changed initWithUserID to initWithUsers
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:[NextController initWithUsers:blockArray] animated:YES];
}
```